# More idiomatic way of testing that a database entry has been modified in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rails-activerecord

In the following integration test using RSpec in Rails 3, I have to use `new_product = Product.find(product)` to get the results of changing what's in the database. This feels a little unidiomatic.

Is there any way of telling an ActiveRecord object to go to the database and get any changes that have happened since the object was created?

Alternatively, is there a more natural way of specifying that the database has been modified for this entry?

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'admin' do
  it 'should edit a product' do
    original_product = create(:product)

    visit products_path
    # ASSUMPTION: Only one product on page.
    click_link 'Edit product'

    fill_in 'product_name', with: 'Foomaster 9000'
    fill_in 'product_price', with: '12.34'

    click_button('Save product')

    # REVIEW: Can the following line be improved?
    new_product = Product.find(original_product)

    # original_product still has old values for product_name and price
    expect(new_product.product_name).to eq('Foomaster 9000')
    expect(new_product.price).to eq(12_34)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reload](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload) method to reload the object using a primary key lookup. This reload happens in place so it will modify your `original_product` variable.

```
original_product.reload
expect(original_product.name).to eq('Foomaster 9000')
expect(original_product.price).to eq(12_34)
```

Comment: Great! I almost had it before, trying `original_product.reload!`, but I must have been thinking of the Rails console method `reload!`. Additional question: do you happen to know an idiomatic way to check if a record is deleted? As mentioned in the docs, if you delete the record in the database, `reload` throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

Comment: I think creating a helper that essentially does `instance.class.exists?(instance.id)` would be nice. With a matcher you can write that like `expect(instance).to be_destroyed`

Comment: Turns out there are actual examples of that http://makandracards.com/makandra/1080-rspec-matcher-to-check-if-an-activerecord-exists-in-the-database

Comment: That looks like it does the job. Cool!